# Does salad require al netilat yadayim?

Tags: halacha, food, netilat-yadayim-washing, vegetables

Assuming the vegetables used to make a salad were washed prior, does eating such a salad require the washing of hands without a Bracha?

Comment: [edit]ing in why you think they *would* require washing would greatly improve this question. ( *If I had a source for you I'd give it to you, but I don't have one off-hand* )

Comment: The veggies are dried first though...

Comment: @DoubleAA You dry your veggies before putting them in a salad?

Comment: @msh210 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salad_spinner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch HaRav [O.C. 158:3](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/13/158/3) paskens that any food normally eaten without using ones hands directly does not require washing of hands without a Bracha.

Salad, as far as I know, is eaten with cutlery, so it would not require washing according to that.

Comment: +1. _Mishna B'rura_ 158:26 cites this rule also.

Comment: I've seen some who are careful not to eat an entire washed vegetable, because of this concern.  i.e. they will wash a carrot or cucumber, but then cut off a bit of the end.  The idea is, as long as one doesn't consume a whole washed vegetable, the ruling of the shulchan aruch doesn't apply, and then the rest of the remaining vegetable could even be eaten by hand.

Comment: @Jake That sounds highly suspect.